# flex 4.1 s:List: how can i force the list to load all the items, not only the visible items?

Tags: apache-flex, list, flex4, image-preloader

I'm creating a facebook application in flex.
I'm actually working on the friends component that shows your friends who are using the application. now, each friend has a profile image.

I created the component using a s:List element.

In the Skin Class of the element i configured the requestedColumnCount to 3, which means it shows 3 friends. i added buttons to scroll left and right in the list.

Whenever I scroll to see a different friend, for a half of a second i see no image because the List component is loading the image in order to view it.

is there a way to make the list preload all the elements so i won't have this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set useVirtualLayout on the List to false, which means it will no longer "recycle" the item renderers.  You may still have a lag when the item renderers initially load the images.  Hope that helps.